# Linear non-homogeneous recurrence relation with combination and power on right-hand side

Tags: recurrence-relations

> Solve the recurrence $h_{n+2} - 2h_{n+1} + h_n = {n \choose 2} + 2^n$ where $n \geq 0$, with initial values $h_0$ = 1 and $h_1$ = 1.

I tried solving this question by writing $h_{n+3}$ term as $h_{n+3} - 2h_{n+2} + h_{n+1} = {n+1 \choose 2} + 2^{n+1}$ and subtracted both the equations after multiplying the original equation by $2$ so that the $2^{n+1}$ term gets cancelled out. Now I am left with an expression which has all the terms $h_{n+3}, h_{n+2}, h_{n+1}, h_{n}$ on the LHS and a quadratic equation of $n$ on the RHS. I don't know how to proceed further so that I end up with an equation of $h_{n}$ only in terms of $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$h_{n+2}-2h_{n-1}+h_n=n(n-1)/2+2^n~~~~(1)$$
First we solve 
$$h_{n+2}-2h_{n-1}+h_n=0~~~~~~~(2)$$, by taking $h(n)=t^n$
we get $t=1,1$ So $$h(n)=(C_1+C_2 ~n)1^n~~~~(3)$$
Next, we solve
$$h_{n+2}-2h_{n-1}+h_n=n(n+1)/2~~~~(4)$$
The HS is second difference of $h(n)$ and RHS is a quadratic of $n$, therefore $h(n)$ in general needs to be a ploynomial of degree four as
$$h(n)=an^4+bn^3+cn^2+dn+e~~~~~(5)$$ inserting it in (4)
we get, $$12an^2+(24a+6b)n~+4a+6b+2c=\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n}{2}~~~~(6)$$
Comparing various coefficients of various powers of $n$ in (6), we get
$a=1/24, b=-1/4,c=11/24$. Hence the solution of (4) is
$$ h(n)=\frac{n^4}{24}-\frac{n^3}{4}+\frac{11n^2}{24}+dx+e~~~~~(7)$$
Next, we solve $$h_{n+2}-2h_n+h_n=2^n~~~~(8)$$
Let $h(n)=k 2^n$ in (8), to get $k=1$.
Finally, the total solution of (1) is
$$h(n)=C_1+C_2~n+\frac{n^4}{24}-\frac{n^3}{4}+\frac{11n^2}{24}+2^n$$
$d$ and $e$ of (7) have been absorbed in $C_1$ and $C_2$, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have one question though, shouldn't equation 1 RHS be n(n-1)/2 instead of n(n+1)/2.

Comment: @vk1234 Yes, thanks, I have now corrected  it, you may see the edit.